# How to save and restore terminal sessions for a specific IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Is there a way in IntelliJ IDEA (either built-in on via a plugin) to store the open **terminal sessions** (their *name*, their *current folder*, ideally also the *history* of the commands and the *output*) and restore them when re-opening the project again?

I often have several Terminal sessions opened concurrently (it's one of the features for which I like IntelliJ!) but it's very sad that their layout and history is forgotten when I reopen the project.

Comment: unitl you have an integrated solution with your IDE I would suggest using iTerm2 https://www.iterm2.com/

Comment: @mccainz I will not swap to MAC only because a single terminal application :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Take a look at Terminator for Linux.  I wish it existed on mac...

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the tip. It is an interesting tool, but it is not what I need. I like the idea of having the terminal sessions integrated with the project I need them for, as they are in IntelliJ. I need the set of terminal sessions open *if and only if* I am working on a project. (Main use case: running *mvn* from command line in various modules separately.) And IntelliJ kind of solved it in 2018.3: it remembers the sessions and their working directories, but not the command history.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Haha, fair enough.  I also use the Terminal in IntelliJ and wish it's history persisted across

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**: this is implemented now in 2018.3 EAP.

**Original answer**

It's not possible at the moment, please vote for the related requests:

- [IDEA-117946](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946) Save terminal tabs between sessions
- [IDEA-134884](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134884) Allow scripted opening, renaming & content of terminal windows

Comment: Yes, it works almost as expected now. IntelliJ remembers the terminal sessions and their working directories, but unfortunately not the command history, which is kind of a missed chance to implement the feature perfectly :)

Comment: I'm not able to restore the history as well. There's a comment on the JIRA that says
"shell history for shells supporting HISTFILE environment variable, e.g. bash, zsh."


Anyone get this to work? I'm on zsh